# Azure Function healthcheck before slot swap?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a function app with a staging slot. I'd like to be able to deploy to the staging slot, and have the app perform an auto swap to the production slot.
In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#Warm-up) for App Service, you're able to write custom warm-up, where "The swap operation waits for this custom warm-up to finish before swapping with the target slot."

Is this possible with an Azure Function?
There seem to be warm-up triggers as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp), but nothing related to the swap operation.

My situation is on deployment to the staging slot, I'd like the swap to get a healthy response from a custom endpoint before continuing with the swap. Is this possible with Azure Functions?

Comment: Please let us know what error you are getting and also share more details with error screenshots.